# How to check user is in rout between source and destination in map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to check user is in given source and destination rout
[image]

if user is out of rout give alert user on wrong rout(missing rout)
I searched on google and and stack overflow but not found any solution

Comment: u need to give an alert urself; and that is what navigation is; u need to map user current location with your route and u need to give some kind of notification like vibration if he goes out of route... :)

Comment: google does not have any api for that . how ever this is a navigation problem and google dont have a navigation api publicly . you have to figure it out your self. this will be a long solution .